# laravel 5.6 Multi Auth problems

Tags: php, laravel, authentication

I got  exception after i made multi auth in my project :

> Argument 2 passed to Illuminate\Auth\SessionGuard::__construct() must be an instance of Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\UserProvider, null given, called in D:\xaamp\htdocs\laravelapi\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Auth\AuthManager.php

Here is a picture:

[image: exception error]

I don't get it, please help, thanks.

here is the auth.php config file

```
    'defaults' => [
    'guard' => 'web',
    'passwords' => 'user',
], 'guards' => [
    'web' => [
        'driver' => 'session',
        'provider' => 'users',
    ],

    'api' => [
        'driver' => 'token',
        'provider' => 'users',
    ],
    'admin' => [
        'driver' => 'session',
        'provider' => 'admins',
    ],
    'library' => [
        'driver' => 'session',
        'provider' => 'libraries',
    ],

],'providers' => [
    'users' => [
        'driver' => 'eloquent',
        'model' => App\User::class,
    ],
    'admins' => [
        'driver' => 'eloquent',
        'model' => App\Admin::class,
    ],
    'libraries' => [
        'driver' => 'eloquent',
        'model' => App\Library::class,
    ],
```

and i made for each guard loginController and login views

Comment: Can you provide how do you access the auth?

Comment: i added the auth.php file in the question